# Enzyme - Mocking utils function used in a component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my React app, I want to test a component which call a utils function from another file.
In a particular case, I *do* want to mock this result. How can I do this using Enzyme and Jest?

This is the code:

```
// MyComponent
import React from 'react';
import { getCalculatedValue } from '../utils';

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    const calculatedValue = getCalculatedValue();
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

And the test:

```
// MyComponent test
describe('MyComponent ', () => {
  it('should be...', () => {
    const myComponent= shallow(
        <MyComponent />
    )
    expect(myComponent.find('....').length).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

The method I want to mock is `getCalculatedValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `jest.mock` to mock the module like this, note that the path `'../utils'` is relative to the test file :

```
jest.mock('../utils', ()=>({getCalculatedValue: ()=> 'someValue'}))
```

If you need to mock the module with different return values for `getCalculatedValue` you need to mock the module with jest.fn(), import it into your test and change the implementation in your tests:

```
jest.mock('../utils', ()=>({getCalculatedValue: jest.fn()}))
import { getCalculatedValue } from '../utils';


it('test1',()=>{
   getCalculatedValue. mockReturnValue('someValue')
})


it('test2',()=>{
   getCalculatedValue. mockReturnValue('anotherValue')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do the following in your test file:

```
getCalculatedValue = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(YOUR_RETURN_VALUE);
```

Now when you create a component tree using the `shallow`, the `getCalculatedValue` will always return YOUR_RETURN_VALUE.

- You could also the the [mockImplementation](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-implementations).
- If you have multiple functions in the utils.js, and you want to mock them all, I would recommend following this doc: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#mocking-user-modules. And just calling `jest.mock('path/to/utils')`

Please follow whatever is best for your use case.